# Exception: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'Date' must have no character or element information item [children]

Tags: xml, xsd

I am doing validation XSD file with XML file but I am getting below exception:

> **Exception:** cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'Date' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's
>   content type is empty.

Basically in my XML file `Date` element is empty

My XML Date element:

```
<Date> </Date>
```

Generated XSD file:

```
<xs:element name="Date">
  <xs:complexType/>
</xs:element>
```

based on this I have created XSD file and validate then it's getting above exception

But if I did without space between date element.

Example:

```
<Date></Date>
```

Then it's working fine.   How can I handle that empty space?

Answer (score 1):

The generator is mistaken:

```
<Date> </Date>
```

and

```
<Date></Date>
```

are not equivalent.

To accept both, use the following definition for `Date` instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Date">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
        <xs:pattern value=""/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Perhaps there is a setting where you can direct your generator *not* to ignore whitespace in `Date` such that it could be guided toward generating the above definition automatically; otherwise, you may just have to replace it manually.

If you're interested in actually allowing dates in your `Date` element too, see **[Allow XSD date element to be empty string](http://Allow%20XSD%20date%20element%20to%20be%20empty%20string)**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if everything is behaving as it should. If the schema defines an element to have empty content, then whitespace content is not allowed. If you want to allow whitespace, then don't define an empty content model. You could for example define it with a simple type of xs:string restricted by a pattern that only permits whitespace.